# Making View conform to UINavigationControllerDelegate and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, camera

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-take-a-photo-using-the-camera-and-uiimagepickercontroller to use built-in camera in my SwiftUI App.

How do I make my main View conform to both UINavigationControllerDelegate and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate (as stated in the tutorial). Where should I put it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
     Button (action: {
         vc.sourceType = .camera
         vc.allowsEditing = true
         vc.delegate = self
         present(vc, animated: true) 
      }) {
          Text("Start Camera")
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot, because delegate must be an object, while view is a struct, so use separated class confirming to those protocols and then just add property of that class to this view.

Comment: The tutorial you are refering to is for UIKit. So no SwiftUI involved.

Comment: You are crossing frameworks look into `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and your `Coordinator` can conform to those protocols.